# ABP.IO Custom basic theme compile errors

Tags: abp

I am quite new to this ABP.IO framework. I am trying to create custom theme by following [this guide](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Blazor/Theming#the-easy-way). But I am getting the following errors,

1. Error   MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Repository\tt\configureawait.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "......\configureawait.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BasicTheme   C:\Repository\tt\EIOS-OS\src\Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BasicTheme\Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BasicTheme.cspro
2. Error   CS0103  The name 'LazyGetService' does not exist in the current
   context Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BasicTheme   C:\Repository\tt\EIOS-OS\src\Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BasicTheme\Themes\Basic\LoginDisplay.razor.cs   33  Active

I commented out the references for .props files in the project file, but the second one is not going away. Please help me to understand these errors.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error,I Decided to temporarily  disable it by commenting out LazyGetService method until i get a proper solution  but in the meantime the login Display component wont respond to state change.

For a **proper fix** I am thinking of creating my own custom Login Display toolbar in the main project.